# API to register domain, add SSL certificate for Google App Engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

we are looking for an API to programmatically register new domains and upload corresponding SSL certificates for an existing Google App Engine application. Background: we would like to offer a DNS-based reverse proxy for our GAE-based service, where our customers can access our application through a domain they own. Once can easily configure new domain names (SNI) manually and upload a matching SSL certificate. In order to automate the process and also limit our exposure to customer-owned SSL certificates, we would like to automate the process.

I have been browsing Google's Management API for Google App Engine (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rpc/google.appengine.v1), but could not find a way to accomplish the aforementioned functionality through that API. Does such an API exist?

Thanks,
Soeren

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no support for this.

There is a feature request for this, created on Nov 13, 2015, which is also addresses Let's Encrypt support.

And there is a hint in it – that somewhere in the wild already exists alpha for "App Engine Admin API - Custom Domains & SSL Certificates"

You can star or comment on this feature request here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35900034

Comment: Also there is a related feature request for custom domains management via API. I hope beta will land soon.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35894480

Comment: investigating revealed updates that appear to be relevant:
https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/App-Engine-users-now-you-can-configure-custom-domains-from-the-API-or-CLI.html
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this isn't supported right now. This might be because of the domain verification process; you can find out more about what serving SSL on a custom domain on App Engine looks like [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/using-custom-domains-and-ssl).